# Qt 6.5 mouse cursor icon not changing

Tags: c++, qt, mouse-cursor

After migrating to Qt6.5 (from Qt6.4) on Debian 11.7, and installing the library *libxcb-cursor0*, some mouse cursor icons are not appearing anymore.

Everything was working before.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.loadFromModule("Test", "Main");

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        cursorShape: Qt.SplitVCursor
    }
}
```

*Qt.SplitVCursor* doesn't appear (I see the default arrow), but *Qt.SizeVerCursor* works.

I have the same problem with other icons, for example the forbidden one.

Qt documentation is talking about a conversion between cursor type and cursor name: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcursor.html

Checking the content of the folder: /usr/share/icons/mate/cursors

*Qt::SizeVerCursor -> size_ver* (there is an icon with this name in the folder)

*Qt::SplitVCursor  -> split_v*  (there is **NOT** an icon with this name in the folder)

Comment: I've noticed that adding the split_v icon in /usr/share/icons/mate/cursors makes the cursor appear. Same of the other cursors.

Comment: FWIW, your code works on Windows (using Qt 6.5.2). I'm not that familiar with xcb, but is it possible they simply don't offer this particular cursor anymore?